# How to decompress gzipped HTTP response?

Tags: gzip, http

File `req` contains the request header:

```
GET /cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm HTTP/1.1^M
Host: docs.oracle.com^M
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8^M
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
^M
```

I run:

```
cat req | nc docs.oracle.com 80 > resp
```

`resp` contains:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
Server: Apache^M
ETag: "726bf43b293f9fc8eac0f8f6b7be3a84:1457459134"^M
Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Mar 2016 14:26:34 GMT^M
Accept-Ranges: bytes^M
Content-Type: text/html^M
Vary: Accept-Encoding^M
Content-Encoding: gzip^M
Date: Sat, 18 Jun 2016 07:04:06 GMT^M
Content-Length: 13163^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
^M
^_<8b>^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Å}ysã8<92>ïÿó)¸Þ<88>}3ïµËâMÎvy<83>â%ªuµ(Õ1^[^[
Z¢mvÉ<92>[Gu¹?ýf<82>^D^HÉ¦  Òîx^[³]¶¬ü^AH$^R<99><89>Dâç^?óÆîìëÄ<97>î^O^Oëë¿ý<8c>ÿHëds÷ñ"Ý\à^Gi²<82>^?^^ÒC^Bß9<^¦¿^_³ï^_/¾\Î<9d>Kwûð<98>^\²<9b>uz!-·<9b>Cº9|¼<88>ü<8f>éê.½ T<9b>ä!ýxñ=KÿxÜî^NÜ^WÿÈV<87>û<8f>«ô{¶L/É/?IÙ&;dÉúr¿LÖéGùCç'é!ù<91>=^\^_èG^Lwy<9f>ìö)à^\^O·<97>^V~|È^NëôÚK^NÉM²O¥ø×<81>4<80>¡^\<93>»T<9a>¦·é.Ý,SéRró^^ì^?¾Ê)N:z<97>nÒ]rØî¸<9e><8e>wÉr<9d>J<9e>3íJ_z³á^@!¾§»Cº<93>þ>Ü®Ré£´Ú.<8f>^Oðí^?@^CÃtw<97>®¤Oén<9f>m7<92>Ü1õ^Kéê´<9d>Õ^R¨^_ö^_<96>»49¤+®5¥#^[<97>^]ù²£Ïô^?jÆ?^Uë_Ï¨wÛ<9b>íaÏ^Q%ëue^Sd<94>Üwk8T<89><93>­<80><»ÍR<9e>7¾&w,í²£U<93>í^KF<8c>o9:h{^Zä4ëlóMÚ¥køð<90> <88>ÜïÒÛ<8f>^W^_>\Áÿ²Í*ýñ^AäòB"ãøxÑÛ>@^_^OO<8f>ðó!ýq¸B¡=Gr·<8f>O»ìîþ^LmµÜ><l7<84>äj    _9Aæ<88>^<82>ÿÛÏûå.{<^T^?L^^^_×Ù^Rä^_ð~K¾'ù^_/$i¿[<9e>·÷Ûþ

   ...continues...
```

Now, apparently the response body is in gzip format. To decompress it, I have copied the response body to `resp-body`. So, `resp-body` contains:

```
^_<8b>^H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Å}ysã8<92>ïÿó)¸Þ<88>}3ïµËâMÎvy<83>â%ªuµ(Õ1^[^[
Z¢mvÉ<92>[Gu¹?ýf<82>^D^HÉ¦  Òîx^[³]¶¬ü^AH$^R<99><89>Dâç^?óÆîìëÄ<97>î^O^Oëë¿ý<8c>ÿHëds÷ñ"Ý\à^Gi²<82>^?^^ÒC^Bß9<^¦¿^_³ï^_/¾\Î<9d>Kwûð<98>^\²<9b>uz!-·<9b>Cº9|¼<88>ü<8f>éê.½ T<9b>ä!ýxñ=KÿxÜî^NÜ^WÿÈV<87>û<8f>«ô{¶L/É/?IÙ&;dÉúr¿LÖéGùCç'é!ù<91>=^\^_èG^Lwy<9f>ìö)à^\^O·<97>^V~|È^NëôÚK^NÉM²O¥ø×<81>4<80>¡^\<93>»T<9a>¦·é.Ý,SéRró^^ì^?¾Ê)N:z<97>nÒ]rØî¸<9e><8e>wÉr<9d>J<9e>3íJ_z³á^@!¾§»Cº<93>þ>Ü®Ré£´Ú.<8f>^Oðí^?@^CÃtw<97>®¤Oén<9f>m7<92>Ü1õ^Kéê´<9d>Õ^R¨^_ö^_<96>»49¤+®5¥#^[<97>^]ù²£Ïô^?jÆ?^Uë_Ï¨wÛ<9b>íaÏ^Q%ëue^Sd<94>Üwk8T<89><93>­<80><»ÍR<9e>7¾&w,í²£U<93>í^KF<8c>o9:h{^Zä4ëlóMÚ¥køð<90> <88>ÜïÒÛ<8f>^W^_>\Áÿ²Í*ýñ^AäòB"ãøxÑÛ>@^_^OO<8f>ðó!ýq¸B¡=Gr·<8f>O»ìîþ^LmµÜ><l7<84>äj    _9Aæ<88>^<82>ÿÛÏûå.{<^T^?L^^^_×Ù^Rä^_ð~K¾'ù^_/$i¿[<9e>·÷Ûþ

   ...continues...
```

Then I have tried `gzip -d resp-body` but it does not work.

What should I do in order to decompress the response?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the headers and what you'll have left is `gzip`-compressed data that can be decompressed with `gzip -d` or `zcat`.
e.g.

```
sed -e '1,/^[[:space:]]*$/d' resp | gzip -d > resp.decompressed
```

The `sed` script deletes the headers - i.e. everything from the first line to the first empty line (`/^[[:space:]]*$/`).

The `[[:space:]]` character-class will make the `sed` script match empty lines and lines containing only space characters (including carriage-returns, `^M`)

BTW, a slightly smarter version of this would extract the `Content-Encoding:` and `Content-Type:` headers, and use the mime-type from that to decide whether to use `cat`, `lynx -dump`, `gzip -d`, `bzip2 -d`, `xz -d` or whatever else to "decode" the data.  But that would probably require writing it in `perl`.

Comment: Wow it worked. But to me, it seems like this method and what I did are the same, yet my method does not work. Could you please explain how is this different than my method (and what is missing in my method)? (I have edited the question in case my method was not clear)

Comment: Maybe something changes when I copy the response body with `^C` to clipboard and than paste it to `resp-body` with `^V`?

Comment: it looks like the response has been opened in less which reinterprets control characters into printable ASCII, the result will not after cut-and paste resemble the original,

Comment: @Jasen Actually I opened it in `vim` but still a similar issue I guess?

Comment: yeah, absolutely.